# How to use implicit casting in expression tree c#?

Tags: c#, .net, expression

I have simplified program, which uses expressions:

```
public class Program
{
    public static IEnumerable<char> foo1()
    {
        //  For some reason I cannot change result type
        return new char[] { 's', '1' };
    }

    public static string foo2()
    {
        //  For some reason I cannot change result type
        return "s1";
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Expression cond = Expression.Condition(Expression.Constant(true), 
            Expression.Call(typeof(Program).GetMethod("foo1")),
            Expression.Call(typeof(Program).GetMethod("foo2")));
    }
}
```

During execution I have following error

> Argument types do not match.

As I understood c# does not use implicit type casting. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When building expressions it's not going to add in implicit conversions for you.  You need to specifically indicate that you want to apply the conversion operator(s) using `Expression.Convert`.

```
Expression cond = Expression.Condition(Expression.Constant(true),
    Expression.Call(typeof(Program).GetMethod("foo1")),
    Expression.Convert(Expression.Call(typeof(Program).GetMethod("foo2")), typeof(IEnumerable<char>)));
```